# A variable not a CFString

Tags: objective-c, cfstring

I'm coding on Ojective-C just for month and get in the deadlock. Need help.
Here is the story:

1. I have a simple class LXPPlayingCard:

   ```
    #import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
    @interface LXPPlayingCard : NSObject {
    @private NSString* cardCV;
    @private int position;
    }

    @property (readwrite, assign) NSString* cardCV;
    @property (readwrite,assign) int position;
    @end

    @implementation LXPPlayingCard
    @synthesize cardCV;
    @synthesize position;
    @end
   ```
2. Also I have hardly more complex class LXPDeck:

   ```
   #import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
   #import "LXPPlayingCard.h"
   @interface LXPDeck : NSObject {
   LXPPlayingCard* cards[100];
   int deckCapacity;
   }

   -(void) fill:(NSString *) cardlist;
   -(void) showList;
   -(int) deckCapacity;

   @end

   #import "LXPDeck.h"
   #import "LXPPlayingCard.h" 
   @implementation LXPDeck
   -(void) fill:(NSString *) cardlist {
       int l,i,j;
       l=[cardlist length];
       j=0;
       for (i=0;i<l;i+=2) {
           cards[j]=[[LXPPlayingCard alloc] init] ;        
           [cards[j] setCardCV:[cardlist substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(i,2)]];
           [cards[j] setPosition:j+1];
           NSLog(@"%@",[cards[j] cardCV]);
           j++;
       }
     deckCapacity=j;
     }

     -(int) deckCapacity { return deckCapacity;}

     -(void) showList {
     NSLog(@"deck capacity:%d",deckCapacity);
     NSString * temp;
     temp=[[NSString alloc] init];
     for (int i=0;i<deckCapacity;i++) {
       NSLog(@"card[%d]=%d, adress:%p",i,[cards[i] position],cards[i]);
       temp=[cards[i] cardCV];
       NSLog(@"%@",temp);
       }
        }

    @end
   ```

which do couple things: fills array of cards with names (setCardCV) from string, and print the content of the deck (showList).
Further I create a class AppController:

```
@interface LXPAppController : NSObject {

}
-(IBAction) openNewDeck:(NSButton * )sender;
-(IBAction) printDeckContent:(NSButton *)sender ;

@end

#import "AppController.h"
#import "LXPDeck.h"


@implementation LXPAppController
    BOOL deckOpened=FALSE;
    LXPDeck* workDeck;

-(IBAction) openNewDeck:(NSButton *) sender{

    if (!deckOpened) {
        NSLog(@"Opening new deck...");
        workDeck=[LXPDeck alloc];
        [workDeck fill:@"pacataca"];
    }

    deckOpened=TRUE;
}
-(IBAction) printDeckContent:(NSButton *) sender {

    if (deckOpened) {
        NSLog(@"Printing deck content...");
        [workDeck showList];
    }
}
@end
```

and two buttons on the main windows which I linked to `openNewDeck` and `printDeckContent` methods.
The problem is that application fall down with error "EXC_BAD_ACCESS" and it happens on `i`=3 because (when i use debugger) `[card[i] cardCV]` is not a CFString.

I tried with different strings to fill the deck, and sometimes the program failed on fist circle of showing `[cards[i] cardCV]`.
I really don't understand what happens, but I guess it somehow connected with pointers and memory allocation rules because there is no problem with simple types of data (`position` for example) and `showList` method works properly if it calls from `fill` method.
Please, give me a hand! I'm going nuts! The program is so simple, that I really nervous about problems in future coding...

Comment: I strongly suggest making use of the NSMutableArray class, cards[j] look c-ish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that

```
[cardlist substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(i,2)]]
```

returns an `NSString` that you do not own. Since you don’t own it, there’s no guarantee that the string will be valid for the lifetime of your `LXPPlayingCard` object. If you want to keep a valid reference to that string, you should modify the declaration of `LXPPlayingCard` so that the `cardCV` property becomes a `copy` property instead of an `assign` one. Replace:

```
@property (readwrite, assign) NSString* cardCV;
```

with:

```
@property (readwrite, copy) NSString* cardCV;
```

By doing this, when you send `-setCardCV:` like:

```
[cards[j] setCardCV:[cardlist substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(i,2)]];
```

`setCardCV` will copy its argument, `[cardlist substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(i,2)]`, and your object will have ownership of that string. This means that the string will remain valid throughout the lifecycle of that object. Remember that since you’ve taken ownership of that string you’re responsible for releasing it. Hence you need to implement a `-dealloc` method:

```
- (void)dealloc {
    [cardCV release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

This means that when the corresponding `LXPPlayingCard` is released, the string stored in `cardCV` is released, too.

Comment: Bavarious, thanks a lot! Now all works fine. By the way, how to became the owner of string form `[cardlist substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(i,2)]]` if I use simple 'NSString*' variable? Use `retain`? 
I mean: 
     NSString * temp;
     ...
     temp=[cardlist substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(i,2)];
     [temp retain];
Am I right? And what should I read to know about all this thins you know? :-)

Comment: @yyk If it’s only a local/automatic variable, i.e., one that’s only used in a particular method, then you _normally_ don’t need to take ownership of it. These variables will be valid throughout the method. But yes, if you need to take ownership of that string, use either `-copy` or `-retain`. You should read the [Memory Management Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html) for a more detailed discussion of memory management.